# Backup a mysql database with a large number of tables (>100,000)

Tags: backup, mysql

I know, really bad database design, but here we are, I have some kind of forum platform (Based on PunBB) and for each forum, I've generated a new set of tables. Really bad idea.

Time has passed and now I have more than 100,000 tables (`SHOW TABLES; SELECT FOUND_ROWS();` - `112965 rows in set (1.21 sec)`). Performance are great though as the tables do the job of indexes and when you make a direct references to one table, it's ultrafast.

The issue is now I am trying to back everything up and to move to another server. Of course, it take forever. I've launched a `mysqldump`:

```
mysqldump --max_allowed_packet=500M --force --opt -u root -pXXXX a > fullbackup.sql
```

And it's still processing, a little more than 12 hours! The backup is already 546 Mb in size and Mysql is still alive and working.

I've tried to copy directly the Mysql files but I've ran into the issue that a lot of tables has been corrupted.

Any idea to speed this up?

Comment: Is there a pattern for the table names? like a common prefix? also what would be the total no. of rows in all the tables? I assume all the tables have same structure

Comment: It's prefixed by the name of each forum. All tables had the same structure. It has been a while ago. I don't remember what I ended doing.

Comment: Obviously there are tradeoffs between performance and reliability so depending on the RAM your Server has, you could always consider copying the tables to in-memory tables and/or outputting the dump file to a file in ramdisk.

I would seriously consider changing your DB schema though!  There are other ways to optimise MySQL performance including sharding.

Comment: What storage engine are your tables using ?

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: It was more than 6 years ago. I don't remember. :) I think I ended up copying the MySQL files. Or waited the 20h. Not sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AWS RDS take a snapshot.

If you are not, use some other snapshot based tool. Percona has one http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtrabackup/. Using mysqldump to back up large databases is extremely slow

If your source database is already corrupt, that's an independent issue.

If you are copying the database and the copy is corrupt, that is because you are doing a "hot copy" which means that you can't copy a database while it's running without a special "snapshot tool". Even file systems have such tools. You need a consistent set of files.

Answer (score 0):

I presume from the fact that your tables are corrupted when you copy the files that you are using InnoDB.

It says in the MySQL documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/5.7/en/backup-types.html)

> Physical backup tools include the mysqlbackup of MySQL Enterprise Backup for InnoDB or any other tables, or file system-level commands (such as cp, scp, tar, rsync) for MyISAM tables.

You can use MySQL Enterprise Backup to perform fast, reliable, physical hot backups (i.e. while the database is running).  I believe it is quiet pricey though.

Answer (score 0):

At my last job we ran MySQL instances with over 160,000 tables.

With that many tables, we had to disable `innodb_file_per_table` and store all the tables in the central tablespace file `ibdata1`. If we didn't, the server couldn't function efficiently because it had too many open files. This should be easier with MySQL 8.0 but in the old version of MySQL we were using, the data dictionary couldn't scale up to so many tables.

To do backups, we used [Percona XtraBackup](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtrabackup). This is an open-source tool that works very similarly to MySQL Enterprise Backup. It performs a physical backup of the data directory, but it does it without the risk of file corruption that you caused by copying files directly. Percona XtraBackup works by copying files, but also copying the InnoDB transaction log continually, so the missing bits of the files can be restored. It's very reliable.

Backing up a database with Percona XtraBackup is a little bit faster, but the greater benefit comes when *restoring* the backup. Restoring a dump file from mysqldump is very slow. Restoring a physical backup like the one produced by Percona XtraBackup can be done as fast as you can copy the backup files into a new data directory, and then start up the MySQL Server.

A recent blog from Percona shows the difference:

[image]

https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/04/02/migrate-to-amazon-rds-with-percona-xtrabackup/